# Mathematical operations in global variable initialization, what does the machine do?

Tags: c++, runtime, compile-time

what does the compiler do when initializing global variables using mathematical operations at the right of the "=" sign?

example:

```
int global1=75;
int global2=32+84;
int global3=(global1+global2);

int main(){
return global3;
}
```

the program should return 191 = (75+(32+84))

what I don't know is whether the result calculated at compile time or at run time

Comment: This [is not valid C](https://ideone.com/NB6oJ0).

Comment: sorry. tags corrected. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`32+84` is a "constant expression", which is a term-of-art in both the C and C++ standards for, essentially, an arithmetic expression whose value can be computed without requiring the compiler to know the value of any variable.  When a constant expression is used to initialize a global variable, as in your

```
int global2=32+84;
```

technically neither the C nor the C++ standard *requires* the addition to be evaluated at compile time, but you'd be hard-pressed to find a compiler that didn't do it that way.  (There are other contexts where the compiler really must evaluate constant expressions at compile time, so it has to have the code to do it, so  it may as well do it all the time.)

`global1+global2` is not a "constant expression".  In C, that means it cannot be used to initialize a global variable; you will get a compile-time error.  In C++, it's allowed, and it is unspecified whether the addition happens at compile time or run time.  The only guarantee is that `global3` will have the correct value by the time `main` begins to execute; in particular, it might *not* have the correct value if observed from a constructor for a global object.

(Empirically, g++ 6 computes the value for `global3` at runtime, whereas clang++ 3.9 does it at compile time, which confirms that both possibilities do occur in practice.)

(In C++, but **not** in C, `global1+global2` would be considered a constant expression if both `global1` and `global2` had been declared `const`.)

Comment: This answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

If you meant c++, I believe global3 is calculated at runtime, as it requires actual code to execute. This is called dynamic initialization, and c doesn't support is, but I believe c++ does. Both c and c++ allow for static initialization, which is what global1 and 2 are, as the actual value is stored on disk. Think of it like this, if someone gives you a recipe that says you need sugar and salt, and you mix those and then add flour, are you going to store mixed sugar and salt around waiting to use the recipe? No. you do the mixing at "runtime". However, you do buy sugar and salt in preparation, you just don’t mix them. The sugar and salt are global1 and 2, and the mixture is global3.